# How to create foreach in StringTemplate? .NET

Tags: c#, .net, templates, stringtemplate

I have to create statement like this:

```
$foreach item in p.Beneficiaries$
                    BeneName $ai.Beneficiaries.IndexOf(item) + 1$ : item.Name
$end$
```

What I have to do to make it works?

Comment: Have you considered using [Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-razor) instead of StringTemplate? Razor is the view engine that ASP.NET MVC is using and has a lot more features than StringTemplate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StringTemplate gives you the $i$ and $i0$ functions inside an iteration, which allow you to see the current index from one or zero. Using the 1 based index function $i$ you could do something like this:

```
Beneficiaries(p) ::= <<
    $p.beneficiaries:{item | BeneName $i$ : $item.name$}; separator="\n"$
>>
```

which produces the following output:

```
BeneName 1 : Bob
BeneName 2 : Helen
BeneName 3 : Dave
```

**EDIT**

Just noticed your calling the IndexOf on a different collection, which renders my suggestion useless. I'll leave the answer anyway in case anyone finds it useful.